# Convolution Neural Network configuration

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

How can I choose a CNN architecture? For example, I have N classes and images of size m*m, how can I determine which layer sizes and count should I use? Is there any universal formula?
In my case I have 16k classes and images of size 64*64. Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no techniques to determine which layer sizes and count you should use. It's more of a trial and error. There is no universal formula. Choose a layer size and train the network. Change it and train again, till you are satisfied with the accuracy.